# How Can I Set Text Field Properties Dynamically or Statically in Android

Tags: android

How can I set the following two properties for a text field in Android:

(**Property 1**) How can I set a text field that contains some text like "Enter a number" but when it is clicked the text field automatically becomes empty?

(**Property: 2**) Suppose I have two text fields in my application. My *first* text field only accepts integers and the *second* text field accepts text like "name, address" etcetera. But by mistakenly I enter some text like "apple" or "ball" in my first text field that only accepts numbers.

How can I set my *first* text field so that when I click on the *second* text field my *first* text field should show a toast message or change the color of inputed data to indicate invalid input?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question...

> How can i set a text field that contain some text like "Enter a number" but as we click on the text field the text should automatically remove from the text field get become empty.

You are looking for the **hint** property that the EditText view has. Read more here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:hint

For the second question, you don't need to go through all that trouble. Just set the **inputType** property for EditText. This will force the keyboard (virtual or physical) to only use either strings or numbers depending on what you specify the input type to be. Read more here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

Answer (score 0):

Property 1) You can do this by adding a ht to the EditText:

```
<EditText

                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Your text here"
 />
```

Property 2)
for Name:

```
  <EditText

                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Your text here"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
     />
```

for Number:

```
<EditText

                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Your text here"
                        android:inputType="number"
     />
```

Have a [look here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) for all parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [setError()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method fot the 2nd issue.